# The commit transaction request has no corresponding begin transaction using ADO.net

Tags: ado.net, sqltransaction

I want to update the records batch wise in SqlTransaction. In every batch i am updating 50 records. If any one record fails to update i want rollback those 50 records. I have written this code in while loop. But i am getting following error randomly.
'The commit transaction request has no corresponding begin transaction'.

Following is my code:

```
Dim _completed as Integer=0
Dim sqlCon As SqlClient.SqlConnection = Nothing
Dim sqlTransaction As SqlClient.SqlTransaction = Nothing
Dim lstq as List(of SqlCommand) 'It contains list of update queries 
sqlCon = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(AIMSCommon.sqlServerConnection)
sqlCon.Open()
While True
    Dim _res = lstq.Skip(_completed).Take(40)
    If _res.Count = 0 Then Exit While
    If sqlCon.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
      sqlCon = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(AIMSCommon.sqlServerConnection)
      sqlCon.Open()
    End If
    Try
      sqlTransaction = sqlCon.BeginTransaction()
                    For Each cls In _res
                        Try
                            cls.Connection = sqlCon
                            cls.Transaction = sqlTransaction
                            Dim i As Integer = cls.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            cls.Dispose()
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            If cls IsNot Nothing Then
                                cls.Dispose()
                            End If
                            Throw ex
                        End Try
                    Next
                sqlTransaction.Commit()
                sqlTransaction.Dispose()
                sqlTransaction = Nothing
                _completed += _res.Count
                Catch ex As Exception
                    sqlCon.Close()
                    sqlCon.Dispose()
                    If sqlTransaction IsNot Nothing Then
                        sqlTransaction.Rollback()
                        sqlTransaction.Dispose()
                    End If
                    If sqlCon IsNot Nothing Then
                        sqlCon.Close()
                        sqlCon.Dispose()
                    End If

                End Try
            End While
            If sqlCon IsNot Nothing Then
                sqlCon.Close()
                sqlCon.Dispose()
            End If
```

Comment: Any one suggest

Comment: Please some one help, Why i am getting this error?